Does there exists a homeomorphism $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(2x) = 3f(x)$ for all $x ∈ \mathbb{R}$.
Does there exists a homeomorphism $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(2x) = 3f(x)$ for all $x ∈ \mathbb{R}$.
$f(x)=x^{log_2 3}$ is a solution which is not a homeomorphism.
But the answer says there exist a homeomorphism.
Is there a trick to find such homeomorphisms?

find two homeomorphisms, one for $[0,\infty)$, the other for $(-\infty,0]$ and join them together.

$f(x)=-5\operatorname{sgn}(x)\lvert x\rvert^{\log_23}$ is one. Its inverse is $g(x)=-\frac15\operatorname{sgn}(x)\lvert x\rvert^{\log_32}$.

Your map $f$ is a self-homeomorphism on $[0,\infty)$ which takes $0$ to $0$. Let us denote by $f_+$. For $x \le 0$ define $f_-(x) = - f_+(-x)$. It is a self-homeomorphism on $(-\infty,0]$ which takes $0$ to $0$. For $x  \le 0$ we have
$$f_-(2x) = -f_+(-2x) = -3f_+(-x) = 3f_-(x) .$$
Clearly $f_+$ and $f_-$ fit together to a homeomorphism $f : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$.

Der Kritiker der Elche has given you one way to construct such a homeomorphism (and as a former moose they clearly know what they are talking about). In fact there are a lot of possibilities. Namely, start off with any strictly increasing, homeomorphism $g:[1,2]\rightarrow [1,3]$. We want to show that any such choice can be turned into a solution for your problem. Simply by defining $f(x)=3^n g(x/2^n)$ for $x\in [2^n, 2^{n+1})$ and $f(0)=0$. To be more precise, this gives you a homeomorphism $f_+:[0,\infty)\rightarrow [0,\infty)$ with the desired property. You can then construct in a similar fashion a homeomorphism $f_-:(-\infty,0]\rightarrow(-\infty,0]$ and joining them gives you what you want.
Let's check that the $f_+$ we have defined above is really a homeomorphism from $[0,\infty)$ to itself. It is enough to show that $f_+$ is continuous, strictly increasing and $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty} f_+(x)=\infty$ (continuity together with $f_+(0)=0$ yields surjectivity by the intermediate value theorem, injectivity follows from strict monotonicity).
Continuity is clear for points in $(2^n,2^{n+1})$ for any $n\in \mathbb{Z}$ as $g$ is continuous and we have $f_+(x)=3^n g(x/2^n)$. The continuity for $x=2^n$ follows from
$$\lim_{x\downarrow 2^n} f_+(x)=\lim_{x\rightarrow 2^n} 3^n g(x/2^n)=3^n g(1)=3^n=f_+(2^n)$$
and
$$\lim_{x\uparrow 2^n} f_+(x)=\lim_{x\uparrow 2^n}3^{n-1} g(x/2^{n-1})= 3^{n-1} g(2)=3^n.$$
Strictly increasing follows from the assumption that $g$ is strictly increasing.
Furthermore, we have $$\lim_{n\rightarrow -\infty} f_+(2^n)=\lim_{n\rightarrow -\infty} 3^{-n}=0$$ which implies together with strict monotonicity that $\lim_{x\downarrow 0} f_+(x)=0$ and thus the continuity at $x=0$.
Finally, we have
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} f_+(2^n)=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} 3^n=\infty$$
and thus by strict monotonicity
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty} f_+(x)=\infty.$$
The family of solutions has the property $f(1)=1$. This is not a real limitation. Indeed, if one has a solution $h$ such that $h(2x)=3h(x)$, then $f(x)=h(x)/h(1)$ satisfies $f(2x)=3f(x)$ and $f(1)$. Also this construction captures all possible homeomorphisms with the desired property.

Elegent and this matches with the answers given in solutions
